# Sending a variable from an input form sends a number instead of the variable value

Tags: variables, autoit

Rather than displaying the text like it should, it just sends a number every time.

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <StaticConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=
$Form1 = GUICreate("Form1", 487, 551, 299, 250)
GUISetBkColor(0x800000)
$what1 = GUICtrlCreateInput("What to run:", 64, 120, 393, 21)
$run1 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Run this!", 64, 152, 129, 25)
$what2 = GUICtrlCreateInput("What to run:", 64, 192, 393, 21)
$run2 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Run this!", 64, 224, 129, 25)
$what3 = GUICtrlCreateInput("What to run:", 64, 264, 393, 21)
$run3 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Run this!", 64, 296, 129, 25)
$what4 = GUICtrlCreateInput("What to run:", 64, 336, 393, 21)
$run4 = GUICtrlCreateButton("Run this!", 64, 368, 129, 25)
$Label1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("NativePrison", 16, 0, 339, 72)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 36, 400, 0, "Arial Black")
GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0x008000)
$Label2 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("AUTO-RUNNER", 184, 64, 271, 49)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 24, 400, 0, "Arial Black")
GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0x000080)
$Label3 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("1", 24, 128, 20, 37)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 18, 400, 0, "Arial Black")
GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0xC0C0C0)
$Label4 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("2", 24, 200, 20, 37)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 18, 400, 0, "Arial Black")
GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0xC0C0C0)
$Label5 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("3", 24, 272, 20, 37)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 18, 400, 0, "Arial Black")
GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0xC0C0C0)
$Label6 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("4", 24, 344, 20, 37)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 18, 400, 0, "Arial Black")
GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0xC0C0C0)
$runall = GUICtrlCreateButton("RUN ALL!", 8, 400, 473, 145)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 48, 400, 0, "Arial Black")
GUICtrlSetColor(-1, 0x000000)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit

        Case $run1
           WinActivate("Minecraft")
           Send("{ESC}")
           Send("t")
           Send($what1)
           Send("{Enter}")
        Case $run2
           WinActivate("Minecraft")
           Send("{ESC}")
           Send("t")
           Send($what1)
           Send("{Enter}")
        Case $run3
           WinActivate("Minecraft")
           Send("{ESC}")
           Send("t")
           Send($what1)
           Send("{Enter}")
        Case $run4
           WinActivate("Minecraft")
           Send("{ESC}")
           Send("t")
           Send($what1)
           Send("{Enter}")
        Case $runall
           WinActivate("Minecraft")
           Send("{ESC}")
           Send("t")
           Send($what1)
           Send("{Enter}")
           Send("t")
           Send($what2)
           Send("{Enter}")
           Send("t")
           Send($what3)
           Send("{Enter}")
           Send("t")
           Send($what4)
           Send("{Enter}")
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't reading the input from the GUI.

All you needed was:

```
GUICtrlRead($what1)
```

I did the same thing today - had not created a GUI input for a while - oops!

Answer (score 1):

`$what1` was a `ControlID`, hence it returns the number 3 when it runs `Send($what1)`.

Not sure what the purpose is after you've already opened Minecraft, but was the `Send($what1)` supposed to run the application path (eq. "C:\application\app.exe") in the `$what1` input box?

If this is what you're looking for then instead of using the `Send()` command, you should read the input and assign it to a variable, also use the `Run()` command.

Here is one example of how you should write the for case `$run1`:

```
    Case $run1
       $w1 = GUICtrlRead($what1)
       WinActivate("Minecraft")
       Send("{ESC}")
       Send("t")
       Run($w1)
       Send("{Enter}")
```